# laying luxury vinyl planks on straight and pitched basement slab

Tags: basement, vinyl-flooring

I am planning to lay luxury vinyl flooring on my basement.

I have a sump pit in my basement.

I have an option to make the floor perfectly straight, or to add a small pitch, so that in the event that there is water, it will flow towards the pit, however the contractor says that there will be 1/8 of an inch unevenness here and there.

Is there an issue with laying luxury vinyl planks on pitched floor or should it be perfectly straight without any pitch?

Comment: The planks want a flat floor, no dips or ridges.  The floor can have any slope if flat from end to end.  Think of a 4x8 sheet that is flat, you can have one end a foot or two(or more) higher and be okay.  bend that sheet an 1/8 or 1/4 inch and not okay.

Comment: There's a difference between "flat" (no dips & ridges), as @crip659 said, and "level" (where the bubble of your spirit level is dead-center between the marks).

Answer (score 1):

The ideal install is flat.  It can be sloped.

LVP is fairly forgiving.  Does your LVP have underlay attached?  Underlay can help to span dips.  Overtime the underlay will compress in areas that are high and stay uncompressed in areas that are low.  The feel of walking on the floor is likely the biggest factor if only dealing with 1/8 dips.

The floor will have some amount of bounce.

The install mechanism for the LVP factors in as well.  If your LVP is click lock you can have the lock fail or the tongue break or disconnect from the grove if a dip happens under the connection and people walk on it.